# js php как правильно валидировать логины email и пароли на наличие запрещенных символов

Tags: javascript, php

подскажите, js php как правильно валидировать логины, email и пароли на наличие запрещенных символов

Comment: Регулярными выражениями

Comment: Использовать фреймвор и его валидаторы, либо регулярки.

Comment: пароль то зачем ограничивать?